# How to remove gap between html elements

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner. I have been following a course for less than a week. I wanted to add credits for the images I used which was not a step in the tutorial. I added a footer and now there is a gap between it and the rest of the div elements. I have searched and the only thing that worked for me was

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px``
}
```

but this messed up some of the rest of the page. I have tried adding margin `0` and padding `0` to many things but no luck. I am sorry if this has been answered before but I do not know what to search for. I have looked on chrome and the gap seems to have something to do with the body but I have set the padding and margin to 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300&family=Montserrat&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <h1>I'm Matthew</h1>

    <p>
      A programmer???
    </p>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">

  </div>
  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="images/photo.png" alt="portrait">
      <h2>Hello.</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img class="" src="images/online-test.png" alt="computer">
        <h3>Web</h3>
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img class="" src="images/france.png" alt="flag">
        <h3>French Learner</h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact-me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>PLease email if you have any questions</h3>
      <p>I look forward to hearing from you.</p>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:">CONTACT ME</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom-container">
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">LinkedIn</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.appbrewery.co/">Website</a>
    <p>© Matthew Osborne.</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computer" title="computer icons">Computer icons created by Freepik - Flaticon</a>
    <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/french" title="french icons">French icons created by IYAHICON - Flaticon</a>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the overflow of the bottom container to `auto`. This removes the unnecessary margin caused by the `p` tag. `p { margin: 0; }` works too

```css
.bottom-container {
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}

footer {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300&family=Montserrat&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <h1>I'm Matthew</h1>

    <p>
      A programmer???
    </p>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">

  </div>
  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="images/photo.png" alt="portrait">
      <h2>Hello.</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img class="" src="images/online-test.png" alt="computer">
        <h3>Web</h3>
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img class="" src="images/france.png" alt="flag">
        <h3>French Learner</h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact-me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>PLease email if you have any questions</h3>
      <p>I look forward to hearing from you.</p>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:">CONTACT ME</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom-container">
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">LinkedIn</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.appbrewery.co/">Website</a>
    <p>© Matthew Osborne.</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computer" title="computer icons">Computer icons created by Freepik - Flaticon</a>
    <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/french" title="french icons">French icons created by IYAHICON - Flaticon</a>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, `<p>` has an intrinsic margin and giving the space. Please see the attachment.

[image: investigation-with-dev-tool]

Removing the margin for the `<p>` gives no space between your name credit and the footer.

[image: after-removing-margin]